# Fragment Backstack after Process Death

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment-backstack

As I observed it seems that the fragment backstack is not retained after process death.
So if I kill my app by putting it to background and call `am kill <app>` it does not recreate the fragment backstack if i take the app to foreground again.

This seems to be the case with both - using `Jetpack Navigation Components` and using `supportfragmantmanager` with `addToBackStack`

After Orientation change everything works as expected. So I don't know whether the backstack is always cleared after process death and cannot be retained or if there have to be some extra steps done to retain the backstack.

Comment: `am kill` and "process death" (i.e., due to memory, etc.) are very, very different things. What makes you think they are related?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Saved instance state survives `am kill`, whereas it does not survive other common "kill" things that a developer might try (swiping the task off the overview screen, red "stop" buttons in Studio). If there is a better way for a developer to simulate the OOM killer terminating the app's process, I'd love to hear about it! I assume that the Jetpack implementation of fragment stores the backstack details in saved instance state.

Comment: @CommonsWare as i found out now the __Logcat__ window offers a __Terminate Application__ button that works and keeps the backstack. But it is interesting to see that it only works if I do the following: App to background -> Terminate Application -> App to foreground -> App to background -> Terminate Application -> bring back go foreground. So i have todo the cycle twice to save and restore the backstack.

Comment: Please provide an explicit code sample that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: not any solutions for this?